# Extracting terms with certain heads in a function

Tags: head

Given a function with several arguments

```
func[a,b,g1[x],g1[x,y],g2[1],g2[g1[1]],3]
```

I would like to extract all arguments with the head `g1` and `g2` as a list. So the output I am looking for is

```
{g1[x],g1[x,y],g2[1],g2[g1[1]]}
```

The way I used to extract **one** head, say `g1`, is simply using the rule

```
/.func[l___,x__g1,r___]:> {x}
```

However, with two heads, this method does not work. I could write a module to do that but I wonder if there is a simpler way like the above rule for one head. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either

```
takeHeads = Cases[#, _g1 | _g2] &;
func[a, b, g1[x], g1[x, y], g2[1], g2[g1[1]], 3] // takeHeads
```

> {g1[x], g1[x, y], g2[1], g2[g1[1]]}

or define `func` itself as

```
func = Cases[{##}, _g1 | _g2] &;
func[a, b, g1[x], g1[x, y], g2[1], g2[g1[1]], 3]
```

> {g1[x], g1[x, y], g2[1], g2[g1[1]]}

Comment: thank you, the method using cases is very useful. I did not know that Cases works inside the function ```func```

Comment: You could also use the 1-arg form of `Cases`, e.g. `takeHeads = Cases[_g1 | _g2]`.

Comment: @mastrok If that surprised you that `Cases` worked on your custom `func` expression have a look at [Everything is an Expression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html). Hope this helps to understand why this worked.

Comment: @Thies Heidecke Yes, I know that everything is an expression. However I thought that Cases only works with List only but not a general head. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[{##&@@func[a,b,g1[x],g1[x,y],g2[1],g2[g1[1]],3]},h=#;Head@#==h&]&/@{g1,g2}
```

> {{g1[x], g1[x, y]}, {g2[1], g2[g1[1]]}}